# Finding zero crossing in consecutive array elements

Tags: arrays, optimization, verilog

I am currently trying to do a really simple comparison with register arrays. I have a register array with numbers that are either positive or negative. I want to make a module that checks the array to see where array element n is positive and array element n+1 is negative. It will then flag the specific location.

Apologies if this is a very simple question or if the answer is already out there, I have tried fixing this for an hour or two and have found no solution.

I am expecting this to update the flag if the first array element is positive and the second is negative. The flag is either indicated as a power (always on) or grounded output. It is never comparing the two values like expected.

```
module flagFinder(
    clk, 
    array, 
    flag
    );
input clk;
input signed [10:0] array;
output reg flag;

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if ((array[0] > 8'd0) && (array[1] < 8'd0))
        flag = 1'b1;
    else
        flag = 1'b0;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the numeric literal `8'd0` is unsigned, so `array[1] < 8'd0` is always false. Both operands of any relational operator need to be signed for the operation to compare as signed. You can fix this by changing the unsigned literal to a signed literal:

1. `0`
2. `8'sd0`
3. `signed'(8'd0)`

Comment: Completely understand the solution.  Signed 0 hurts a little.